# Subdomain with Xampp + Cloudflare

Tags: xampp, subdomain, cloudflare

I install Xampp on Windows VPS.

I add subdomains with Cloudflare:

```
subdomain1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
subdomain2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
subdomain3 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This this httpd-vhosts.conf content:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/"
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ServerAlias www.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain1.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/subdomain1"
    ServerName subdomain1.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain1.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/subdomain1.mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/subdomain1.mydomain.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "E:/subdomain1">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain2.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/subdomain2"
    ServerName subdomain2.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain2.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/subdomain2.mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/subdomain2.mydomain.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "E:/subdomain2">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain3.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/subdomain3"
    ServerName subdomain3.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain3.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/subdomain3.mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/subdomain3.mydomain.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "E:/subdomain3">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I browse from my own PC:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --> It shows content of E:\index.html -->RIGHT!

http://subdomain1.mydomain.com --> It shows content of E:\subdomain1\index.html -->RIGHT!

But:

http://subdomain2.mydomain.com --> It doesn't shows content of E:\subdomain2\index.html --> show content of E:\index.html -->WRONG

http://subdomain3.mydomain.com --> It doesn't shows content of E:\subdomain3\index.html --> show content of E:\index.html --> WRONG

Same with other subdomain 4, 5, 6...

I wonder why only subdomain1.mydomain.com show correctly.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Remove block:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/"
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ServerAlias www.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```